# Loop into Javascript object and show in table

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html-table

I am using JavaScript JSON object. I am not sure this is the right way to write JSON object :-

```
var address={
    details:{
        "martin":[{"full_name":"James Martin"},{"address":"Florida"},{"phone":"897657834"}],
        "luthar":[{"full_name":"Luther king"},{"address":"Boston"},{"phone":"9856568789"}],
        "jonson":[{"full_name":"Jonson vierra"},{"address":"New york"},{"phone":"98654567887"}]
    }
}
```

Now, I want to show every elements of each person in a table. I can do this manually by writing:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td><script>document.write(address.details.martin[0].full_name)</script></td>
<td><script>document.write(address.details.martin[1].address)</script></td>
<td><script>document.write(address.details.martin[2].phone)</script></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Like this for all 3 people, but I want to grab full details of every person by using a loop. 
How can I do this easily by using a loop?

Comment: You might want to think about using a binding library like [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) for something like this.

Comment: actually i don't wanna use any kinds of library right now. Cause i am newbie in javascirpt so i need to know from root. :)

Comment: Fair enough, but using libraries and learning JavaScript aren't mutually exclusive. Also don't get in the bad habit of inlining JavaScript like that. Finally, what you have isn't actually valid JSON since `details` isn't enclosed in quotes, but it's not clear why you want JSON rather than just an object literal anyway.

Comment: JSON is usually easy to use. And it can create array inside array inside array.. . So it's easy to decorate and call.

Comment: Not that easy apparently since you're JSON isn't valid, plus *exactly* the same is true of an object literal. It's actually pretty much exactly the same except you don't need to enclose the property names in quotes.

Comment: this jSON object is invalid ? But when i call, it's working and don't showing any error.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors because it's not JSON, it's an object literal. Go ahead and paste it [here](http://jsonlint.com/) and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
for (var i in address.details)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + address.details[i][0]['full_name'] + '</td><td>' + address.details[i][1]['address'] + '</td><td>' + address.details[i][2]['phone'] + '</td></tr>');
}
```

To follow up this code should output a table with the data you require:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    var address={
        details:{
        "martin":[{"full_name":"James Martin"},{"address":"Florida"},{"phone":"897657834"}],
        "luthar":[{"full_name":"Luther king"},{"address":"Boston"},{"phone":"9856568789"}],
        "jonson":[{"full_name":"Jonson vierra"},{"address":"New york"},{"phone":"98654567887"}]
        }
    }
    </script>
    <table border=1>
    <script>
        for (var i in address.details)
        {
            document.write('<tr><td>' + address.details[i][0]['full_name'] + '</td><td>' + address.details[i][1]['address'] + '</td><td>' + address.details[i][2]['phone'] + '</td></tr>');
        }
    </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: i believe `address.details[i]` is an array

Comment: sorry rushed code, always bad, I've edited it now. Should work.

Comment: I believe Rodrigo has a better answer for your situation though. Also I don't understand why you're putting script tags in the table cells, it's unecessary

Comment: @AlvinC Really a good and short answer. Nice ! 
but if i try to enter whole table. i mean including
`<table></table>` tag. it is not writing. 
note: i wrote `<table>` tag outside of loop.

Comment: @slash-bang I've edited the answer to show you the exact script that you need. I would suggest changing the JSON if possible though.

Comment: Putting the key-value pairs within an array makes it more difficult to work with. There's no need for the array. You can still use the first names as references to `object`s instead of `array`s

Comment: @AlvinC beside this `table` tag can write into script tag. I checked it.

@js1568 how can do this ?

Comment: Condense to: `"martin":{"full_name":"James Martin","address":"Florida","phone":"897657834"},`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var personName in address.details) {
  if (address.details.hasOwnProperty(personName)) {
    address.details[personName]
    //  [{"full_name":"James Martin"},{"address":"Florida"},{"phone":"897657834"}]
    // you could now loop through the personName's array
  }
}
```

Do you have control over the data structure at all? It seems a little convoluted?

Comment: actually i don't want full data in a person ( include ` bracket or "` . i just need such as martins full_name `James martin data in a table.